# Python Code to Check Multiple Files on Gitlab repository by group ID

Tags: python, gitlab, repository

I want to check multiple files in the repository, and whether the files exist or not in the Python script below.

The case is, that the file in the repository exists but the results say the file is not found.

```
import requests
from urllib.parse import quote_plus
import json
import os

# Set your GitLab API URL, private token, and group ID as environment variables
gitlab_api_url = os.getenv("GITLAB_API_URL", "https://gitlab.com/api/v4")
private_token = os.getenv("GITLAB_PRIVATE_TOKEN", "xxx")
group_id = os.getenv("GITLAB_GROUP_ID", "xxx")

def get_project_ids(api_url, private_token, group_id):
    endpoint = f"{api_url}/groups/{group_id}/projects"
    headers = {"PRIVATE-TOKEN": private_token}
    
    response = requests.get(endpoint, headers=headers)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        projects = response.json()
        return [(project['id'], project['name']) for project in projects]
    else:
        print(f"Failed to retrieve projects for group {group_id}. Status code: {response.status_code}")
        return []

def check_files_in_project(api_url, private_token, group_id, project_id, project_name, filenames, output_filename):
    # Specify the private token for authentication
    headers = {"PRIVATE-TOKEN": private_token}

    # Create a dictionary to store the output information
    output_data = {
        "group_id": group_id,
        "project_id": project_id,
        "project_name": project_name,
        "files": []
    }

    for filename in filenames:
        # Encode special characters in the filename and construct the URL
        encoded_filename = quote_plus(filename)
        endpoint = f"{api_url}/projects/{project_id}/repository/tree?recursive=1&path={encoded_filename}&ref=dev"

        print(f"\nChecking for file: {filename} in project {project_name}")
        print(f"Constructed URL: {endpoint}")

        # Make the API request to get the repository tree
        response = requests.get(endpoint, headers=headers)

        # Check if the request was successful
        if response.status_code == 200:
            # Parse the JSON response
            repository_tree = response.json()

            # Check if the specified file exists in any folder
            file_found = any(filename == item.get("name", "") for item in repository_tree)
            print(f"File {filename} found in project {project_name}: {file_found}")

            # Append file information to output_data
            output_data["files"].append({"filename": filename, "file_found": file_found})
        else:
            print(f"Failed to retrieve repository tree for project {project_name}. Status code: {response.status_code}")

        # Append output data to a single JSON file after checking each file
        with open(output_filename, 'a') as json_file:
            json.dump(output_data, json_file, indent=2)
            json_file.write('\n')  # Add newline to separate entries

# Get the list of project IDs and names in the group
projects_info = get_project_ids(gitlab_api_url, private_token, group_id)

# Specify the list of filenames you want to check
filenames_to_check = ["serverless.yaml", "serverless.yml"]

# Single output file for all projects
output_filename = "output_all_projects.json"

# Open the file with an initial '[' to start a JSON array
with open(output_filename, 'w') as json_file:
    json_file.write('[')

# Iterate over each project ID and check for the files in any folder
for project_id, project_name in projects_info:
    check_files_in_project(gitlab_api_url, private_token, group_id, project_id, project_name, filenames_to_check, output_filename)

# Close the file with a ']' to close the JSON array
with open(output_filename, 'a') as json_file:
    json_file.write(']')
```

This the results on JSON file

```
[{
  "group_id": "gid",
  "project_id": xxx,
  "project_name": "name,
  "files": []
}
{
  "group_id": "gid",
  "project_id": xxx,
  "project_name": "name",
  "files": []
}
{
  "group_id": "gid",
  "project_id": xxx,
  "project_name": "names",
  "files": []
}
```

note:

- xxx my personal data.

Your help is very valuable for me, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repositories.html#list-repository-tree), `path` param is for specifying subdirectories and not files:

> The path inside the repository. Used to get content of subdirectories.

At the moment you have `&path=<filename>` parameter in the endpoint:

```
endpoint = f"{api_url}/projects/{project_id}/repository/tree?recursive=1&path={encoded_filename}&ref=dev"
```

That's why it is not working. So just delete `path` parameter from the endpoint.

Also keep in mind pagination - according to the docs - `per_page` parameter default value is 20. It can influence because you are using `recursive` flag - that means if you have many files and subdirectories in your projects - it will be impossible to handle all paths via one request.